# Doctrine saves changed but not persisted entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a REST Api that accepts a bulk collection of entities and then validates them one by one in order to save only valid ones and ignore invalid ones. I tried to achieve this by

```
foreach($bets['bets'] as $bet){
    $bet['betRound'] = $betRound->getId();
    $bet['user'] = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $betObj = $this->getBetForGame($bet['game']);
    $singleForm = $this->formFactory->create('bet', $betObj);
    $singleForm->submit($bet);
    if($singleForm->isValid()){
        $em->persist($betObj)
    }
}
$em->flush();
```

This checks every single entity and only persists it if it was valid. Somehow when I submit 12 valid entities an 4 invalid ones, the flush is still committing all 16 and changing the database values even for the invalid ones. 
Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $em->refresh to restore any invalid bets to their original condition.

Update: if the bet objects are already being managed then there is no need to call persist on them.

```
foreach($bets['bets'] as $bet){
    $bet['betRound'] = $betRound->getId();
    ...
    // Basically reloads invalid objects
    if(!$singleForm->isValid()) $em->refresh($betObj);
}
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I built a very similar solution to this, but are not refreshing the entities, but detaching them. I am not sure if that makes a big difference in my case.

Comment: I guess it would be interesting to see which method is faster.

Answer (score 0):

`flush()` method synchronize every change in the unit of work with the database. Try to flush only the valid valid ones separately:

```
foreach($bets['bets'] as $bet){
    $bet['betRound'] = $betRound->getId();
    $bet['user'] = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $betObj = $this->getBetForGame($bet['game']);
    $singleForm = $this->formFactory->create('bet', $betObj);
    $singleForm->submit($bet);
    if($singleForm->isValid()){
        $em->persist($betObj);
        $em->flush($betObj);
    }
}
```

I do not know if it is typo, but you forgot a `;` here:

```
$em->persist($betObj)
```

Comment: Thas what I had in the first place, but didn't like the multiple flushs for performance reasons.